# Как написать в Active Record связь и получение связанных данных из API?

Tags: php, yii2, rest

У меня есть REST API.

Есть три сущности `Entity1`, `Entity2`, `Entity3`. На каждую сущность привязана `Active Record` и соответствено таблица из БД.

Связь `Entity1` и `Entity2 1:1`, связь `Entity2` и `Entity3` - 1:N.

В моделях прописаны и `extraFields()` и геттеры, которые возвращают `ActiveQuery`. В общем, по стандарту в *Yii2*. В итоге если делать запрос вида:

```
/entity1?expand=entity2.entity3
```

то получу данные с вложенностями как и полагается:

```
{
    "...": ...,
    "...": ...,
    "entity2": {
        "...": ...,
        "...": ...,
        "entity3": [
            {"...": ...,},
            {"...": ...,},
            {"...": ...,},
        ]
    }
}
```

Всё работает отлично. НО. Теперь `entity2` и `entity3` планируют располагать где-то вовне, на отдельном сервере, сервисе и от них данные будут прилетать через REST API.

**Вопрос:** как это можно всё безболезненно организовать так, чтобы у меня осталась возможность получать связанные данные в запросе вот так: `/entity1?expand=entity2`  и `/entity1?expand=entity2.entity3`  и чтобы особо не пришлось что-то переделывать в `ActiveRecord` модели(ях)? Я думал, что `entity2` и `entity3` переделаю из AR в наследники от Model и что-то незначительное допишу переопределю и всё... Но кажется всё намного сложнее. Подскажите, куда двигаться, как реализовать.

---

P.S. По-тупому я могу реализовать: например в геттере первой модели прописать условие: если в `GET` запросе есть `expand=entity2.entity3`, то сделать запрос по API  и в геттере добавить `entity2` с вложенным `entity3`, если в запросе просто `expand=entity2` - вернуть объект только со вложенным `entity2`. Но это очень глупо. Хочется чего-то более элегантного

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь, то можно сделать так. В extraFields остается Entity2, но в модели изменяем getEntity2. Там прописываем получение данных из api, заполняем модель Entity2 и отдаем результат. Потом уже в модели Entity2 изменяем getEntity3, в которой проделываем тоже самое, что с Entity2 и должно корректно отрабатывать

Comment: Так не получится, потому что чтобы ходить по связям, геттер должен вернуть `ActiveQueryInterface`, а не `ActiveRecordInterface`. Поэтому на `Entity2` всё и закончится.